# dividing a long column to many short ones by a condition

Tags: r, function

i have a very long column of numbers. i want R to make a new column every time the value changes from zero. 
example for the column:

```
90.1194354 
87.94788274 
80.34744843 
64.06080347 
30.40173724 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
16.28664495 
23.88707926 
29.31596091 
48.85993485 
13.02931596 
0 
0 
0 
7.600434311 
20.62975027 
29.31596091 
32.5732899
```

for this example i want to get 3 columns.

thanks!

Comment: Talking of columns, that suggests that you already know that the "groups" will be equally long. If not: what do you want R to do with the different lengths? Apart from that: this is probably better aimed at Stack Overflow...

Comment: off topic as not a statistical question.  Try R-help.  but you will have a (solvable) issue  if your "columns" are different lengths as in the example - what sort of object would have 2 columns with 5 elements and one with 4?

Comment: If they're the same lengths, you don't need to look for zeros - it's really easy. If they aren't the same length you need to give more information about what you want to end up with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you expect to have columns of different lengths. Pad them with `NA`?

This solution uses `rle` and splits the vector into a `list`:

```
temp <- c(90.1194354, 87.94788274, 80.34744843, 64.06080347, 30.40173724, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16.28664495, 23.88707926, 29.31596091, 48.85993485, 
          13.02931596, 0, 0, 0, 7.600434311, 20.62975027, 29.31596091, 
          32.5732899)

x <- rle(temp == 0)
split(temp, rep(seq_along(x$lengths), times = x$lengths))[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
# $`1`
# [1] 90.11944 87.94788 80.34745 64.06080 30.40174
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 16.28664 23.88708 29.31596 48.85993 13.02932
# 
# $`5`
# [1]  7.600434 20.629750 29.315961 32.573290
```